# datatable editor Unable to automatically determine field from source

Tags: javascript, datatable

Having some problems in getting the editor of datatable to start working. keep getting the error Unable to automatically determine field from source. In my particular case the table is already loaded in html and on edit have to send the edited field to the server. Using inline edit functionality of the editor. Code for the initialization of datatable and editor is as follows

```
 var ajaxBase = {
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData: "false",
        headers: { "X-CSRFToken": '{{ csrf_token }}' },
        data:  function ( d ) {
          console.log(d)
              return JSON.stringify(d)
        }
   };
  var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
          table: "#response",
          fields: [ 
              {
                  name: "shop-name",
                  data:"shop-name"
              }, 
              {
                  name: "title"
              },
              {
                  name: "price"
              },
              {
                  name: "details",
              }
          ]
      } );
  $('#response').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child, :nth-child(3), :nth-child(7), :nth-child(8))', function (e) {

          editor.inline(this);
      } );

  var table = $('#response').DataTable( {     
            fixedHeader: true,
            responsive:true,
            columns: [
              { "name": "group" },
              { "name": "shop-name" },
              { "name": "Thumbnail" },
              { "name": "title" },
              { "name": "price" },
              { "name": "details" },
              { "name": "url" },
              { "name": "manage" }
              ],
                columnDefs: [{
                      render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        if (data.length<100){
                          return "<div class='text-wrap width-200'>" + data +"</div>";        
                                            }
                          return "<div class='text-wrap width-200'><div>" + data.slice(0,100) + "<a style='cursor:pointer;font-weight:bold;' onclick='show(this)'>...Show More</a></div><div style='display:none;'>"+data+"    <a style='cursor:pointer;font-weight:bold;' onclick='hide(this)'>Show Less</a></div></div>";
                      },
                      targets: [5]

                  },
                       {
                      render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                          return "<div align='center' class='text-wrap width-20'>" + data+"</div>"
                      },
                      targets: [0,1,3,4]
                  },
                 {

                      render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                          return "<div align='center'><a style='cursor:pointer;color:blue;' href='"+data+"'>Open</a></div>"
                      },
                      targets: [6]
                  },

                 {
                      render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                          return "<div align='center'><img src='" + data+"' width='60px' height='60px'></img></div>"
                      },
                      targets: [2]
                  },
               ],
                     } );
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Ensure that the `fields` in your "editor" are completely matching with the columns specified in `$('#response').DataTable( ... )`

2- Use data keyword instead of name while specifying the columns.

```
fields: [ 
              {
                  name: "group",
                  data:"group"
              }, 
              {
                  name: "shop-name",
                  data:"shopname"
              },
              {
                  name: "Thumbnail",
                  data:"thumbnail"
              },
              {
                  name: "Title",
                  data:"title"
              },
              {
                  name: "Price",
                  data:"price"
              },
              {
                  name: "Details",
                  data:"details"
              },
              {
                  name: "URL",
                  data:"url"
              },
              {
                  name: "Manage",
                  data:"manage"
              }
          ]

...

columns: [
              { data: "group" },
              { data: "shopname" },
              { data: "thumbnail" },
              { data: "title" },
              { data: "price" },
              { data: "details" },
              { data: "url" },
              { data: "manage" }
         ],
```